# React Native - Suggestions for creating an errorHandling for my React Native application

Tags: react-native, error-handling

I'm working on a React Native project and I really wanted to make an Error Handler to improve the display and handling of errors in my application. Can you suggest a library or some way to capture all the errors in my application with pure JavaScript?

I researched a tool called error boudary which is widely used in ReactJS but I was wondering if anyone has used it for React Native.

I haven't tried to create it yet because I'm just starting out